# Kodular Web Component "Post Text with Encoding" Block

Tags: android, google-apps-script, post, character-encoding

Somewhere in my app I need to write some values to a Google Sheets document.
When the text is in English alphabet everything is fine and the Google Sheet updates perfectly.
But When I send Persian text, empty string is received on the Google side.

I’m using a Google App Script doPost(e) function to send data from my App to Google Sheets.
First, I used the simple Post Text Block and I saw problem with Persian text. Then I replaced it with the Post Text With Encoding Block, but the problem still persists.

Here’s the App Script code:

```
function doPost(e) {

var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(“https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/**********tmk/edit#gid=150301410”);

var sheet = ss.getSheetByName(e.parameter.sheet);

var customerID = e.parameter.customerID;

var name = e.parameter.name;

var gender = e.parameter.gender;

var consultantID = e.parameter.consultantID;

var phone = e.parameter.phone;

var city = e.parameter.city;

var dateOfBirth = e.parameter.dateOfBirth;

var satisfaction = e.parameter.satisfaction;

var referredIDs = e.parameter.referredIDs;

sheet.appendRow([customerID, name, gender, consultantID, phone, city, dateOfBirth, satisfaction, referredIDs]);

return ContentService.createTextOutput(“Row with customerID " + customerID + " appended.”);

}
```

I’ve also attached a screenshot of my blocks.

[image]

Would be really grateful for any help :)

First, I used the simple Post Text Block and I saw problem with Persian text (Google sheet received empty string) . Then I replaced it with the "Post Text With Encoding Block", but the problem still persists.

Comment: Do you know where along the chain the text is getting lost? I would recommend throwing in some `console.log` statements in your `doPost` to help you pinpoint the issue.

Comment: Unfortunately, no message is written to console if I call the function from my App.

Comment: Update to question: I don't know if the encoding parameter value "UTF-8" is right for the Kodular function (see image above). Kodular documentation lacks proper explanation and examples to see what are possible values for the "encoding" parameter. Is it right to be written as "UTF-8" in uppercase or should be provided in some other way?

Comment: TBH I am no expert on encoding, although I think UTF-8 is fine and should be fine whether it's written as `UTF-8` or `utf-8`.  Are you unable to see any logs under `Executions` on your google script? Usually that's where you go to see the logs when a app is triggering your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED:

The Persian texts needs to be encoded in an appropriate format for Web Post or Get.

For example "گلابی" becomes "%DA%AF%D9%84%D8%A7%D8%A8%DB%8C" after encoding.

There's a special function available in Kodular (UriEncode) which does just that.

[image]